# how to post text to friend wall in Facebook in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

i want to post text to friend wall but there is some problem by using this code...

```
-(IBAction)PostToBuddyWall
{    
    NSMutableDictionary  *postVariablesDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];    

    [postVariablesDictionary setObject:@"LOL" forKey:@"name"];
    [postVariablesDictionary setObject:@"helllo" forKey:@"message"];

     Facebook *fb = [((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]) fbInstance];
    [fb requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed",self.fbFriendsInvited] andParams:postVariablesDictionary andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:nil];

    NSLog(@"message: %@",postVariablesDictionary);
    [postVariablesDictionary release];

    UIAlertView *facebookAlter=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Posted successfully on facebook" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil, nil];
    [facebookAlter show];
    [facebookAlter release];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

please give the suggestions if u have...
thanks !!

Comment: What actually happens when you try this? "There is some problem" is uselessly vague.

Comment: ya..it gives the error ...bad url

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 NSMutableDictionary  *postVariablesDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];    

[postVariablesDictionary setObject:@"LOL" forKey:@"name"];
[postVariablesDictionary setObject:@"helllo" forKey:@"message"];

//Post to friend's wall.
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed", self.fbFriendsInvited] parameters: postVariablesDictionary HTTPMethod:@"POST" 
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
{
         NSLog(@"%@",result);
}];
```

Comment: what is the FBRequestConnection?

Comment: Which facebook SDK are you using ?